# Docker container starts with some Linux directories with a non-root user ownership

Tags: linux, docker

I have the following issue:

Having the same Docker image in the host A and host B (a node-alpine based image), when I do a simple 'docker run' in the host A, the Linux directories (taking /var as reference) remain with root:root ownership, but when I execute the same command in the host B, several directories (including /var) change their ownership to the user and group of the user executing the 'docker run' command.

Both hosts have the same OS (SLES 15) and docker version (Docker 20.10 ce).

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does your  `docker run` use bind-mounts? (using the `-v` or `--volume` flag, e.g. `docker run -v <some-path>:<container-path>` ?)

Comment: No, it is as simple as "docker run -it <image> sh". Nothing more.